# unfortunately your app has stopped workin

Tags: java, android

This is one class of my project, but when ever I am executing my application I am getting error *"unfortunately your app has stopped working"* on startup.
If I remove the comment before the statements 
`TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` 
and the statement 
`mytextview.setText("write executed");`
then I am getting error. It is running fine when these two statements are in comment.

```
public class CommonResources extends Activity
{
   String filename = "myfile", s = "Hello World";
   FileOutputStream outputStream,fout;
   FileInputStream fileInputStream;
   Context ctx;
   //TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   void write()
   {
      //mytextview.setText("write executed");
      try
      {
         File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), filename);
         outputStream = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
         outputStream.close();
      } catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Check the variable R.id.textView1, what's the value? What's the value of mytextview?

Comment: Where is onCreate? Where is setContentView? Please read up on the [basics](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: The most common cause of your error message is a NullPointerException on the application startup. Here `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` may throw one. As said Skynet, you need a onCreate method containing a setContentView() call, [as stated in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: Check if the view with id textView1 is a TextView  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it something like this:

```
TextView mytextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mytextview.setText("write executed");
}
```